# running multiple ruby test methods from a test file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, automated-tests

I am using the following command to run a **test** method from the test file:

```
./bundle exec ruby -Ilib test_file.rb -n test_method
```

Can some one please suggest as how to proceed, if I need to run **multiple methods** on command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to pass multiple `-n` options, like this:

```
./bundle exec ruby -Ilib test_file.rb -n test_method -n test_another_method
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found a temporary solution for the above problem. I made a call to all the test methods from a single method(I created it). Then used the following command to run it:

```
./bundle exec ruby -Ilib test_file.rb -n test_method_containing_required_to_run_tests
```

In the test file:

```
def test_method_containing_required_to_run_tests
test_method1
test_method2
test_method3
...
end
```

But when a method fails, the methods after the failing method are not called at all.